# Pushbutton + relay + hall sensor

Tags: switches, relay, hall-effect

I need to find a solution to start a relay with a momentary pushbutton and stop it with a hall sensor. The rellay would control ~1000W.

I was thinking of two possible solutions:

1. **analog**: pushbutton activates latching relay and hall sensor deactivates it.
2. **digital**: pushbutton tells microcontroller to latch regular relay until the signal from the hall sensor is detected.

I was also thinking to add a short delay when the hall sensort triggers and I guess in the first case I could do it with a 555 timer and in the second case, it would be easy to do that in software.

What is the recommended way to do this? Does anyone know if an off the shelf solution exist for something like this?

Comment: What voltage? Part number and datasheet link for the Hall sensor? Relay details?

Comment: The relay switches 220V and the hall sensor works at 12V. I don't have the datasheet currently but I can change both the relay and the hall sensor if it makes sense.